# Focus does not work

Tags: html, css, flexbox, pseudo-element

I have the following code: [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/rujife/8/edit?html,css,output).

I want the two flex-boxes to initially have grey as background, once we click on one box, its ENTIRE background becomes white. `.flex-box .col textarea:focus` works as expected, whereas `.flex-box .col:focus` does not work: the background colour of the text (eg, `html`, `css`) is always grey.

Does anyone know what's wrong?

```css
.flex-box {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  height: 300px;
}
.flex-box .col {
  border: 1px solid green;
  flex: 1;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hide;
  background: #F7F7F7;
}
.flex-box .col textarea {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  resize: none;
  border: 0;
  font-family: monospace;
  background: #F7F7F7;
}
.flex-box .col:focus {
  background: white;
}
.flex-box .col textarea:focus {
  outline: none;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-box">
  <div class="col" id="html-panel">
    <h2>html</h2>
    <textarea name="html"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="col" id="css-panel">
    <h2>css</h2>
    <textarea name="css"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Edit 1:**

Actually, once we click on the textarea of a box, I want the background of its title to also become white systematically. It annoys me to set an event listener with JavaScript (because I have already several event listeners). Isn't there a way to realise this with CSS alone?

Comment: It's because only textarea gets focus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the `textarea` gets `:focus` not the `div`. One way to achieve your result with CSS alone is to add an extra `div` for the background and use the sibling selector when the `textarea` is focused.

```css
.flex-box {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  height: 300px;
}
.flex-box .col {
  border: 1px solid green;
  flex: 1;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hide;
  background: #F7F7F7;
  Position: relative;
}
.flex-box .col textarea {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  resize: none;
  border: 0;
  font-family: monospace;
  background: #F7F7F7;
  Z-index: 1;
}
.flex-box .col label {
  display: block;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  Z-index: 1;
}
.flex-box .col:focus {
  background: white;
}
.flex-box .col textarea:focus {
  outline: none;
  background: white;
}
.flex-box .col .background {
  Position: absolute;
  Top: 0;
  Left: 0;
  Right: 0;
  Bottom: 0;
  Height: 100%;
  Width: 100%;
  Z-index: 0;
}
.flex-box .col textarea:focus ~ .background {
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-box">
  <div class="col" id="html-panel">
    <label for="html">html</label>
    <textarea id="html" name="html"></textarea>
    <div class="background"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col" id="css-panel">
    <label for="css">css</label>
    <textarea id="css" name="css"></textarea>
    <div class="background"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Will tidy this answer up a bit later - difficult to answer on a mobile!

Comment: Thanks for the idea... I am building [this](https://jsbin.com/rujife/11/edit?html,css,output): once we click on the title, I want its col (including its textarea) to become white as well (sorry it was not clear in the beginning). I am still debugging this...

Comment: Nice... I have also debugged [the mine](https://jsbin.com/rujife/19/edit?html,css,output), but I think using `label` is definitely better...